# On Pressing Enter Key It Move to Other Page Rather Then Calling Java Script (Code Attached)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, textbox

when i press enter key on txtZip textbox It MOve to other page rather then calling JS i wanna set another text box value eqaul to txtZip

```
<asp:TextBox Style="text-align: center" ID="Txt_Zip" runat="server" Width="120px"
                    Text="Zip" onkeypress="return runScript(event)"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox Style="text-align: center" ID="Txt_Second" runat="server" Width="120px"
                    Text="Zip"></asp:TextBox>

function runScript(e)
{
if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13)
{
   var zip =document.getElementById("txtZip").value;
   document.getElementById("txt_Second").value=zip;
}

}
```

as i ahve one button also that re direct to another page on click how to restrict that on pressing enter key on text box just call JS ??

Hopes for your suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
         $("input[id$='Txt_Zip']").on('keypress', function(e) {
           var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
             if(code == 13) { 
              $("input[id$='Txt_Second').val($(this).val());
              return false;
           }
         });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `e.preventDefault();` inside the if statement braces. This tells the event to not carry out the default action (submitting the form).

```
function runScript(e)
{
if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13)
{
   var zip =document.getElementById("txtZip").value;
   document.getElementById("txt_Second").value=zip;
   if (e.preventDefault) {
       e.preventDefault();
   }
   return false;
}

}
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` isn't available in native JS is it? JQuery isn't tagged here.

Comment: Yes, it is. Although admittedly not in IE<9, so a `return false` fallback is a good idea. I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function runScript(e)
{
if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13)
{
   var zip =document.getElementById("txtZip").value;
   document.getElementById("txt_Second").value=zip;
   return false;
}

}
```

Comment: it is still redirecting to another page

Comment: Try adding an `alert` or `console.log` to make sure the event is actually firing.

Comment: it is alerting means its firing event but redirectin to another page